# Fiddler says reponse is gzip encoded , IE dev tool does not say so

Tags: asp.net, iis, compression

Im working on a web application to be hosted internally and accessed by ~150 people. Because of the nature of the business, lof of images move between browser and the server.  I want to ensure that other content like  text is compressed. I think I have made the necessary setting on the IIS 7.5 server.

Now when I request a page and check the response headers with the fiddler2 tool, it says "Transport
Content-Encoding:gzip.

And I also see a message "Response is encoded and may need to be decoded before inspection. Click here to transform"

However when I see the response headers using IE developer tools, network tab, there is no mention of gzip encoding.

So my question is : Is my content really compressed as fiddler2 says or is it not compressed like IE tools show.

As always all help/guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: use a packet sniffer and see what's on the wire. if it's not gzipped, you'll see html and whatnot. if it IS gzipped, you'll see "random" ascii garbage.

Comment: Thanks @MarcB. I used the Wireshark and we had 2 servers one doing compressiona and another not. Easily found out via wireshark wheather the data was getting compressed or not. It would have been good if the IE dev tools had atleast indicated that it had decoded the data on the wire before displaying.